# How do we indicate a volume fraction like 0.05 in procedure descriptions?

Tags: terminology

I'm translating a Russian biotech text, and there's this sentence with a number without measurement units:

> The contents of the wells were discarded; the wells were washed three times with 200 µL of Buffer containing **0.05 of Tween 20**.

I was told that this figure indicates a volume fraction, and is dimensionless, hence no units after it. Will this be understood by the native speaker of English as-is, without any units, as in my quote?

Or is it better to write it down as:

> The contents of the wells were discarded; the wells were washed three times with 200 µL of Buffer containing **5% (v/v) of Tween 20**.

Or maybe like this:

> The contents of the wells were discarded; the wells were washed three times with 200 µL of Buffer containing **5 vol% of Tween 20**.

Is there a way to retain **0.05** and somehow indicate that this is a volume fraction?

Comment: Your ways are the correct ones.  "0.05 v/v" won't pose any doubts, too. Or "0.05 volume fraction" as you did here. But I vote for your two options.

Comment: Your ways are the correct ones.  "0.05 v/v" won't pose any doubts, too. Or "0.05 volume fraction" as you did here. But I vote for your two options.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be wise to include units, because how would you distinguish between mass and volume fractions? Options 2 and 3 that you present are both seen in the scientific literature and text books. My opinion is that option 3 is the least ambiguous way to present both the numeric value and the context (i.e. the units).